# How to group by sum without using sum function in select?

Tags: sql

There's a customer table having id, firstname,  country and invoice total( for each customer). I need to write a query displaying list of countries (in descending order) according to revenue generated by each country. 
 [image: expected result]
 I'm trying the following  the following query:

Select country, sum(invoicetotal)  from customer group by country order by 2 desc

[image: result of above query]

The output is according to the expected result but with an additional column of sum(invoicetotal).  I cannot figure a way to order the countries according to the sum of their imvoicetotal without using sum()  function in select.

Comment: Edit your question and show your query.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
select country
from t
group by country
order by sum(revenue) desc;
```

I think all databases support the use of aggregation functions in the `order by` even if the value is not in the `select`.